# How does the Lucene tool Luke determine a file count?

Tags: lucene, ibm-connections, filenet, luke, ibm-css

Using Luke, it is showing 348K files in the Lucene index.  Our repository, after being queried using SQL commands via ACCE (IBM Connections storing files in Connections Content Manager [ie. FileNet]) is coming back with 345K files users have uploaded.  Is there any way to explain the 3K difference?  It seems odd that Luke would report MORE documents than the actual repository contains.

Are there control docs?  Versions?  I can see 325 docs listed on the Luke page indicating it is also counting deletions, but that still leaves a 3K difference (the actual difference was originally closer to 3.5K when counting deletions).  Over time, we have been monitoring the increase in the number of documents users are adding, and they are increasing at a consistent rate.  However, the discrepancy between Luke and the file count returned by ACCE is increasing.  We are now approaching 4K, even when not taking into account the deletions listed by Luke.  How can we explain this anomaly?

Thanks.

Comment: I would imagine that you are dealing with multiple versions.